# Add data in head section of the template using plugin in DatingScript

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am  developing a plugin but  stuck at a point where i want to add a JS variable before `</head>` tag using plugin.

I have used view::includeJavascript() for adding JS variable but it appends site URL with that variable. It allows me to add variable in footer as well but i wanted to add this variable in head of the template.

`<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'> var data = ".$data."; </script>` this is what I wanted to add in the head of the template.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to insert and what gets inserted exactly? Your description is vague and the line of code looks like you're using PHP rather than JS.

Comment: Yes i am doing it with PHP. I have tried :
view::includeJavascript("data = ".$data.";"); which add the code in header but append the script like this:
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>head.js("http://site1.mysite.com/var data = ".$data.";); </script>
and

view::includeJavascript("data = ".$data.";","footer"); bur it add the code in footer and i want it to be added in head.